# C3 not declared in this scope when running MIDI example code

Tags: arduino-ide, midi

I'm trying to run the [MIDI example from Arduino.CC](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MidiDevice) in Arduino Studio.

I am using an Arduino Leonardo, which has USB HID capabilities. I have installed the library as mentioned:

[image: MIDI Library installed]

When I press the compile or upload button, it says:

```
'D3' was not declared in this scope
```

What's wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: the error happens when the source code is being compiled .... the upload is not attempted ... upload only happens when the code compiles without errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pitches for the notes are taken from [pitchToNote.h](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/MIDIUSB/blob/master/src/pitchToNote.h). In there you can see definitions for the notes like:

```
#define pitchC3  48
```

It seems that the names were changed from `C3` to `pitchC3`.

I am not 100% sure, but my guess is that this was done to avoid conflicts between the note `A3` and the analog input `A3` (and silimar).

So, in line 25 of the example code, add `pitch` for all notes:

```
const byte notePitches[NUM_BUTTONS] = {pitchC3, pitchD3, pitchE3, pitchF3, pitchG3, pitchA3, pitchB3};
```